# Are there MSNP Implementation for Java, ActionScript (Flash) exist?

Tags: java, flash, actionscript, protocols, msn

Interesting if there any Implementation of MSNP Live Messanges Protocol for Java or  ActionScript (Flash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one for ActionScript: http://code.google.com/p/as3msnp/

Comment: Sweet! Look like what I need !

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the only one: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/java-jml

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft new policy towards Skype MSNP12 protocol is not working.

major host of following reference are now responding

[Microsoft Service host and ports](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927847?wa=wsignin1.0)

So, JML lib is now useless which work over MSNP8-15. 

Here is another thread over MSNP - [What's the future of MSNP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474111/whats-the-future-of-msnp)

Answer (score 0):

I used the below API in a chating server we were developing 4 years ago , at that time MSNP10 was working with us.You can download the API from below link and I found it very easy to getting started with this API based on the documentation and examples they have provided on their website.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/java-jml/

Good Luck.