# What's the future of MSNP

Tags: protocols, deprecated, skype, msn

This is my first question here.
I've been researching a lot about this but nothing came up because the news about this are too recent.

I'd really need to know the future of MSNP when skype replaces msn.
What will happen to apis that connect to @hotmail.com, @msn.com or similar through MSNP??

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by NoPyGod, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live//default.aspx states the following:

> We recently announced that we’ll begin to encourage Messenger users to start using Skype. As a result, the Messenger developer program will end. Existing implementations that use Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) will continue to work until October 2013. Existing implementations that use MSP will continue to work until March 2014.

Comment: Well that turned out to be a complete lie, it's shutting down.

Comment: According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live//default.aspx - MSP will continue to work until March 2014. Is MSP the same as MSNP? I'm sorry for the tone of my earlier comment. I had actually started working on an MSNP application (We are talking about the protocol used by hotmail.messenger.com:1863 - MSNP8, MSNP9, MSNP12 etc?) before this announcement so I was pretty disappointed to hear Microsoft were shutting down MSN. Even if they are shutting down I still want to finish the project before that happens because I'm learning a lot.

Comment: I've clarified it a bit, as I was mixing up services and protocols in the question.

Comment: Could you clarify whether MSNP is MSP? That's what I'd like to know - thanks

Comment: According to [this blog post](http://messengergeek.wordpress.com/2014/05/30/small-possibility-of-messenger-shutdown-this-weekend/), nobody knows what MSP ("mobile service proxy") really is, but it's gone and it was not MSNP.